# Error inflating class fragment. Must specify unique android:id, android:tag, or have a parent with an id

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I am trying to run a fragment but my application keeps on crashing when i run it. I am trying to load the main activity so that i can display the webview in it but i am having no luck.

MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Fragment code

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.uk/");

        return view;
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bashirsentongo.webviewapp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.bashirsentongo.webviewapp.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.example.bashirsentongo.webviewapp.WebViewFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="layout.main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"/>
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The fragment tag in the XML needs an ID

Answer (score 12):

From the official documentation:

```
Note: Each fragment requires a unique identifier that the system can use to restore the fragment if the activity is restarted (and which you can use to capture the fragment to perform transactions, such as remove it). There are three ways to provide an ID for a fragment:

Supply the android:id attribute with a unique ID.
Supply the android:tag attribute with a unique string.
If you provide neither of the previous two, the system uses the ID of the container view.
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Also you find an example here using an id for the fragment:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confused with how to implement a Fragment.

The Fragment is loaded onto a viewgroup (typically FrameLayout) contained within the Activity, there isn't really a need for the Fragment to have a FrameLayout in your case. (Because the TextView and Webview will overlap)

That being said, once you have a FrameLayout in place of the use of the `<fragment>` tag, think about, how would you load the Fragment in the Activity? A `FragmentTransaction`. What does that need? An id for the view container to load the Fragment. And that's your error - you don't have one.

Comment: @Mrnerd If this has solved your question, please use the checkmark next to an answer to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3):

All of your `<fragment>` containers should have unique ID. Then just set ID for root `RelativeLayout`.